How to remove (1) from macOS subfolders?
Because of a botched attempt at folder all of my apps and documents to new iMac via Google Drive I've ended up with a slew of folders, subfolders, and files showing the iteration of copying I've attempted on them leading to folders/files having (N) appended to the end where N is the number of attempts i.e. "Folder (1)" or "Folder (2)" and sometimes several i.e. "Folder (1) (1)".
I found an AppleScript that I thought would correct this below:
set stopCharacters to " (1)"
set stopCharacterCount to (count stopCharacters)

set sourceFolder to choose folder default location (path to home folder)

tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFiles to (every file in sourceFolder ¬
        whose name contains stopCharacters and name ends with "pdf") as alias list
end tell

repeat with aFile in sourceFiles
    tell application "Finder" to set aFileName to name of aFile
    set stopOffset to (offset of stopCharacters in aFileName) + stopCharacterCount - 1
    set newFileName to text 1 thru stopOffset of aFileName & ".pdf"
    try
        tell application "Finder" to set name of aFile to newFileName
    on error errorMessage
        set dialogText to "The source file " & quote & aFileName & quote & ¬
            " could not be renamed. The error message was:" & return & return & errorMessage
        display dialog dialogText buttons {"Cancel", "Skip"} default button 1
    end try
end repeat

I'm a total newb when it comes to AppleScript and I have not been able to make it work. It wouldn't be the end of the world if I had to go through and remove the (1) from everything, but it would sure make my life easier if I could.
Could someone give me a hand or a clue?

The issue appears to be that you were re-adding the unwanted string to the new name of the file. Try this.
use scripting additions -- as some commands are part of standard additions
set webbo to ".pdf" -- variable will allow for better ease of use
set stopCharacters to " (1)"
set stopCharacterCount to (count stopCharacters)

set sourceFolder to choose folder default location (path to home folder)

tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFiles to (every file in sourceFolder ¬
        whose name contains stopCharacters and name ends with webbo) as alias list
end tell
log sourceFiles

-- set newNameList to {}
repeat with aFile in sourceFiles
    tell application "Finder" to set aFileName to name of aFile
    set stopOffset to (offset of stopCharacters in aFileName) - 1 -- should be offset of last character to keep
    log stopOffset
    set newFileName to (text 1 thru stopOffset of aFileName)
    log {aFileName, newFileName}
    try
        tell application "Finder" to set name of aFile to (newFileName & webbo)
        -- set end of newNameList to newFileName
    on error errorMessage
        set dialogText to "The source file " & quote & aFileName & quote & ¬
            " could not be renamed. The error message was:" & return & return & errorMessage
        display dialog dialogText buttons {"Cancel", "Skip"} default button 1
    end try
end repeat
-- newNameList -- list of new file names

Notes

Removed stopCharacters from determination of offset. This is why the script did nothing
Moved the extension to later in script to make it easier to see what the script is doing at this point
All of the added log operations are optional
If you have a large set of numbers to remove [eg (14), (15)] then you could put the parts of the script after choose folder into its own loop that provides the number inside the brackets for stopCharacters. The stopCharacters lines would also need to be inside the loop.
You could also have the script work its way through sub-folders. If you have a lot of files/folders, and you find the performance horrid, then you could use System Events rather than the Finder to cycle through them all, which should take less time.

For future reference, please explain what running the script did rather than just that it didn't work, even if the result is that nothing changed. It helps when trying to figure out what is happening on someone else's computer.

Thank you, but I found an app called Better Finder Renamer that's helping me tackle this. And I make not of made it clear but I was and are completely clueless on how to execute the script I was given. It looks like I need to buckle down and watch some videos or take a course to familiarize myself with AppleScript. Again, thanks for the help.
